# How can I lock files under 'proof-of-work' where unlocking them would not take very long?

Tags: encryption, storage, lock

In other words, a way to encrypt files, not with the main purpose of security, but with the purpose that it would take a longer commitment to access them. For example, it would require around 24hrs to open with an average personal computer (average performance growth could be ignored).

Possible use: Suppose someone has addictive personal files, but doesn't want to delete them, as they may need them years into the future. Storing files on external hard disks, in that case, would be impractical and unsafe since the final intention is to keep data secure on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a *short* random password and throw it away.

File encryption programs **already use** something very similar to a proof-of-work function: [a KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). When you provide a password it is never used raw as the key, but fed through (at the very least) a hash function, and modern encryption tools use "key derivation functions" that are designed to be bruteforce-resistant, such as scrypt, Argon, PBKDF2, or Bcrypt.

For example, when LUKS or KeePass use PBKDF2 they adjust its number of rounds so that every attempt will take approximately ~1 second. That means on a 4-core machine only 4 passwords per second could be attempted, so even just a five-digit numeric password would take ~7 hours to crack. (Of course, the same number of rounds on a better CPU could be twice as fast, but it's *not* going to be 100× faster.)

Comment: It would be worth mentioning that you would likely need to combine it with a password cracking tool such as [John the Ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/)